# Access "ease of access" text size settings

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

As far as I know, there is no way for a Windows Phone application to get access to the "ease of access" settings through some kind of API (as confirmed by Microsoft engineers in several occasions online, see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7cd21981-7f48-4f62-b1cd-ed63229143d7/font-size-changes-and-ease-of-access-settings-in-wp8?forum=wpdevelop) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/f9e818cf-a8e2-4d27-9c30-7b5ab65861dc/accessibility-options?forum=wpdevelop)).

However, I recently noticed that the last [WhatsApp](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=218a0ebb-1585-4c7e-a9ec-054cf4569a79) version for Windows Phone 8 indeed *does* support the "ease of access" settings and changes its font size accordingly (just like the native messaging application). This is a feature I find extremely useful for accessiblity and it would be very useful for all applications out there.

Is WhatsApp using some kind of private/undocumented API or did I miss something?

Comment: wondering the same thing. any hints on that?

Comment: Text enlargement was apparently added to Windows Phone 8.1 apps (based on XAML/WinRT). Still nothing for Silverlight 8.1 apps though, as far as I know.

Comment: New Windows Phone 8.1 apps have automatic text scaling. WP Silverlight 8.1 apps have access to the [UISettings.TextScaleFactor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.textscalefactor.aspx) property instead. No solution for older Silverlight 8.0 apps though.

Answer (score 1):

> Is WhatsApp using some kind of private/undocumented API

No. They are using the out of the box stuff for it. They are a Universal App and not Silverlight which maybe the big difference.

> did I miss something

If [textblocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.aspx) have [IsTextScaleFactorEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.istextscalefactorenabled.aspx) they will automatically scale with the Ease of Access settings. This is something you need to plan though because it can just make a bad UX. I would suggest exploring the out of the box apps to see how they approached it (email is a good example IMHO).

There is some great guidance around text scaling, contrast and out accessibility information [on the MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868163.aspx) too, which covers the above and more.